# Downloading CSV files using Selenium Python resulting into ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, automation

I am trying to download some open governmental data using Python3 and Selenium. My code is working fine and I can download files, but after downloading a couple of files, the code stops and I get the following error:
`ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="views-field views-field-field-short-name file-container csv">...</div> is not clickable at point (859, 530). Other element would receive the click: <div id="confirmation_popup" class="confirmation-pop-6749107">...</div> (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)`

This is my code. I am new to Selenium. Please help what and where am I doing something wrong. Some answers on SO recommend using EC, but my code is on a pop-up, so I don't know how can it be used there.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://data.gov.in/catalog/prison-statistics-2018?filters%5Bfield_catalog_reference%5D=6749015&format=json&offset=0&limit=82&sort%5Bcreated%5D=desc")

time.sleep(25)

print(driver.title)

time.sleep(10)
list_of_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("csv")

for item in list_of_items:
    item.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Non-commercial')]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'R&D')]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='edit-submit']").click()
    print("Item download successfully!")
    time.sleep(5)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am using Google Chrome 84.

Comment: A popup is handled just the same as any other other part of the page - identify the action to remove it (e.g. an button click) and do it. You say you already download a few files correctly - so does it always fail at the same point? - which point is that?  (do that manually and capture what needs to be done)   - Expected Conditions and webdriver wait will potentially help you, but, if you're waiting for an object that doesn't appear you'll just get timeout errors.

Comment: open devtools while your script is running, switch to the console and you'll see when the page stops working you get `js_BhpfWlbTlCE4gzC2W1wI6UhvmYrBo76E1qe3jnAy-z8.js:8630 POST https://data.gov.in/save_reasons net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`   - Refresh the page and you get a captcha... So the site is detecting you're trying to skim it and it's stopping you

Comment: So, what is the alternative in that case? Does it mean, this site won't allow bots to download the data files? Let me try today with Scrapy and see if it works. My guts say, it won't. However, let's try.

Comment: I tried doing it with Scrapy, but there is CAPTCHA, so the page couldn't proceed. What else can we do? Please help.

Comment: It's a difficult one. Looking at the site - you go to the site and get session cookies, you click the CSV link, that uses in-browser JS to generate a unique form ID, that ID is submitted in the post to save_reasons along with the session cookies, that post returns a token, that token is used in the download link to download the file......! I've not got an easy answer for you. It's deliberately designed to force in-browser steps, and those steps also detect automation

Comment: Looking at the page - there is a request API link which requires an account... is that an option? create an account and go wholly api?  (i didn't go past the account create stage so no idea what's behind that wall)

Answer (score 0):

This is worst practice in selenium.
Whilst it is possible to start a download by clicking a link with a browser under Selenium’s control, the API does not expose download progress, making it less than ideal for testing downloaded files. This is because downloading files is not considered an important aspect of emulating user interaction with the web platform. Instead, find the link using Selenium (and any required cookies) and pass it to a HTTP request library like libcurl.

Comment: Justin, I did doing that. However, this website requires one to manually fill in the information in the dialogue box before the downloading starts. That's what I was trying to automate. If it's not the best way, do you recommend using Scrapy? Wouldn't I get the same issue then?